# Get Bitmap attached to ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-bitmap

Given

```
ImageView image = R.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
image.setImageBitmap(someBitmap);
```

Is it possible to retrieve the bitmap?

Comment: yes it, possible when u click on image we will get that if you want this requirement let me know.

Answer (score 826, accepted):

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Comment: Be carefull to check if your `image.getDrawable()` can actually be cast to `BitmapDrawable` (to avoid `IllegalCastExceptions`). If, for instance, you use layers in your image then this snippet will be slightly different: `Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)((LayerDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getDrawable(0)).getBitmap();`

Comment: This will, occasionally, return a bitmap with some or all black pixels.

Comment: this will not return the original bitmap nor the filtered bitmap if you have applied on the drawable/imageview.

Comment: Returns null for me. Not sure why. My `ImageView` does not have a drawable in it though, but a photo bitmap.

Comment: @NoniA. - you should open a new question about it

Comment: does this work if image in `ImageView` is set from `URI`? `imageView.setImageUri()`

Comment: @praneethkumar it does work in my scenario. Thumbs up for this awesome answer!

Answer (score 46):

This will get you a `Bitmap` from the `ImageView`. Though, it is not the same bitmap object that you've set. It is a new one.

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
```

=== EDIT ===

```
 imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
 imageView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
                   MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
 imageView.layout(0, 0, 
                  imageView.getMeasuredWidth(), imageView.getMeasuredHeight()); 
 imageView.buildDrawingCache(true);
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getDrawingCache());
 imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: when it "does not work", what happens? Does it return null or throw exception or what?

Comment: it returns null. sometimes I have to reload the page for it to actually appear.

Comment: Gives me a null pointer. :( On this line: `Bitmap bmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageView.getDrawingCache());`

Comment: drawingCache is deprecated in Kotlin

Answer (score 3):

Write below code

```
ImageView yourImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourImageView);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)yourImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Comment: i get AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Answer (score 3):

For those who are looking for `Kotlin` solution to get `Bitmap` from `ImageView`.

```
var bitmap = (image.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
```

Comment: i get AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Answer (score 0):

This code is better.

```
public static  byte[] getByteArrayFromImageView(ImageView imageView)
    {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable());
        Bitmap bitmap;
        if(bitmapDrawable==null){
            imageView.buildDrawingCache();
            bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
            imageView.buildDrawingCache(false);
        }else
        {
            bitmap = bitmapDrawable .getBitmap();
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
```

Comment: is it imageView.getDrawable(); -> means getting the image from drawable folder? CMIIW.... @Ahmad

Comment: No. You can use this code.`Bitmap imagenAndroid = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.jellybean_statue);`

Answer (score -4):

Other way to get a bitmap of an image is doing this:

```
Bitmap imagenAndroid = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.jellybean_statue);
imageView.setImageBitmap(imagenAndroid);
```

Answer (score -10):

try this code:

```
Bitmap bitmap;
bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Comment: Could you describe the enhancement over @Arslan 's accepted answer?

Comment: you'd better explain why your answer solves his problem