# Get Bitmap from an ImageView in Monodroid project

Tags: bitmap, imageview, xamarin.android

Is it possible to retrieve the bitmap of an imageView ?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306623/get-bitmap-attached-to-imageview) but I'm getting NullPointerException and the edited code don't work in monodroid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your answer. Finally I did it like that :

```
var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.image);
Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.Drawable).Bitmap;
```

ps: I had a NullPointerException because the imageView was in another view.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get access to the assigned image via the *Drawable* property. Make sure to check for null before accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

here is a working example i'm using it.

```
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap save = view.getDrawingCache();
```

where `view` is `ImageView` and if you trying to save it. well here is my saving method to get the view from my imageview and save it as `.PNG`

```
    void Save() {
    if (null != view.getDrawable()) {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        save = view.getDrawingCache();
        final File myDir = new File(folder);
        myDir.mkdirs();
        final Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        final String fname = "StyleMe-" + n + ".png";
          file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            save.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                    Uri.parse("file://"
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Image Saved",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                    "Something Went Wrong check if you have Enough Memory",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        final Toast tst = Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                "Please Select An Image First", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        tst.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        tst.show();
    }
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
}
```

and here is my variables.

```
        String folder = "/sdcard/Pictures/StyleMe";
        static File file;
```