# Bitmap wallpaper change every 10 seconds android

Tags: android, wallpaper

Hello I'm trying to create bitmap wallpaper. But this bitmap changes every 10 seconds. How can I accomplish this?

This is what I have tried:

```
 // I have declared 
 int[] images = {R.drawable.donna, R.drawable.donna1, R.drawable.marian,
        R.drawable.marian1, R.drawable.marian};


 Handler mHandler = new Handler();

 ImageView imgView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imgView =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        while (true) {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(10000);
                                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                                    public void run() {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        // Write your code here to update the UI.
                                        Random ran = new Random();
                                        imgView.setImageResource(images[ran.nextInt(images.length)]);
                                    }
                                });
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
```

But my question is how do I integrate the function/method for setting this as wallpaper?

Any help is truly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `postDelayed()` to change your image wthin a specified timeframe:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler(); 
Runnable __runnable = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        Random ran = new Random();
        imgView.setImageResource(images[ran.nextInt(images.length)]);
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);              
    }
};
new Thread(__runnable).start();
```

For your second question, see the link below:

[how to set image as wallpaper from the ImageViev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424157/how-to-set-image-as-wallpaper-from-the-imageviev)