# How to make user set wallpaper manually?

Tags: android

I do set wallpaper function but it's not manually like this
[set wallpaper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB6ie.jpg)

Code:

```
private void setWallpaper()
{
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    WallpaperManager manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        manager.setBitmap(bitmap);
        Toast.makeText(ViewWallpaperActivity.this,"Done!",LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(ViewWallpaperActivity.this,"Error!",LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15424344/12034846

Comment: same outcome of my code

Comment: have you added permission in manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code for Set wallpaper sheet:

```
private void setWallpaper(){
    Uri uri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bitmap);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
    intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpeg");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as:"));
}
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```