# Determine size of whitespace in ImageView

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-imageview

I have a floor plan which is centred in an ImageView. The aspect ratio of the image is preserved so there is some space on either side of the image (indicated in red colour).

How can I determine the width of this red space in pixels or dp?

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/floor_plan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/floor_plan2"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/locateMe"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    />
```

I note that the margins have been set to 0dp in the dimens.xml file.

Comment: post the whole xml for that.

Comment: post your layout file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's only math :

```
int originalImgWidth  = bitmap.getWidth();
int originalImgHeight  = bitmap.getHeight();

float scale = screenHeight * 1f / originalImgHeight;  
// since your img will fill the screen vertically

float marginSize =  (screenWidth - (originalImgWidth * scale)) /2;
```

Note that the size might be negative if the image is bigger than the screen horizontally ^^

see how to get the bitmap [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306623/get-bitmap-attached-to-imageview)

see how to get screen size [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions/1016941#1016941)

Comment: If I just wanted the width of each red section and not the area, could I just use: marginSize = (screenWidth - originalImageWidth) / 2 ?

Comment: in my example the 'marginSize' is the width of each red section. (just a note for futur readers)