# How to view an Image View to a linear layout in android dynamically on andorid

Tags: java, android, android-layout, singleton, android-imageview

I have two activities. One that submits the data and one that shows the submitted data. I am able to add the images to the first activity fine and the data is then stored in a singleton data object with a ArrayList instance called "images".

The problem I have is that when trying to retrieve the images from the image array and display them it crashes the app. I have tried to debug the code and it runs perfectly until you get to the last line:

```
attachmentLayout.addView(image,imParams);
```

The Images are stored in the singleton correctly and when you debug it, it shows that they are in fact there.

I tried to figure it out for myself, but I can't find what it is. I am quite new to android programming so help would be much appreciated. I have added my code that tries to get the images below.

```
if(values.getImage()!=null){

        int count = images.size()-1;
        for (int x=0;x<=count;x++){
            //declare attachments and get image from arraylist<ImageView>
            LinearLayout attachmentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.attachments);
            ImageView image;
            image = images.get(x);
            //set parameters
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams imParams =
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(90,270);
            image.setBottom(attachmentLayout.getBottom());
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            image.isShown();
            //add to linear layout
            attachmentLayout.addView(image,imParams);

        }
    }
```

**Edit:**
This is the logcat I get when the app restarts after is crashes. I don't believe this is helpful though.

```
08-24 12:34:18.522    4782-4820/com.example.jules_gribble.test I/Adreno﹕ QUALCOMM build                   : 065751b,
Build Date                       : 04/15/15
OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.07
Local Branch                     :
Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BF64.1.2.1_rb2.9
Remote Branch                    : NONE
Reconstruct Branch               : AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF64.1.2.1_RB2.05.01.00.081.016 + 065751b +  NOTHING
```

Comment: Show your logcat error

Comment: No error is given. It just restarts the app

Comment: why is your `count = images.size() - 1`?  just use the images.size in your for loop

Comment: Just the way I was taught to code I could equally do that and take away the >= in my condition. Doesn't matter which way you do it

Comment: No error is given? If your app restarts it generates a lot of lines in your logcat. Try increasing the limit-lines of your logcat viewer and locate the error

Comment: I have added the logcat that shows in the edit above. I don't believe this is helpful though @KlitosG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to answer my question myself. Turns out it was crashing because I wa overlooking that in the submit activity it was declared

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(Test.this);
```

This meant it could not be used in a different activity (Test is the name of the class of the submit activity which will be changed).

To solve this I changed it to

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(Submitted.this);
```

where submitted is the name of the submitted activity. I then needed to get the bitmap of the image and set the bitmap to the new imageview.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)images.get(x).getDrawable()).getBitmap();
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

I found this from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306623/get-bitmap-attached-to-imageview).

Hope this will help someone in the future.