# Adding an on touch coordinate and pixel color display

Tags: android, image, colors, coordinates, rgb

My current code allows you to take an image and display it inside an image view. How would I implement the ability to touch anywhere on the image and display the color at that pixel, the color would then fill a solid object such as a rectangle to display what it is. I'm hoping the solution contains RGB values as i need them for my application later on.

```
import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;


    import java.io.File;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private static final int CONTENT_REQUEST = 1337;
        private File output = null;
        Button button;
        ImageView imageView;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CameraButton);
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Image_view);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

                    output = new File(dir, "COMP4Image.jpeg");
                    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(output));

                    startActivityForResult(i, CONTENT_REQUEST);

                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + "/COMP4Image.jpeg";
            imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't provide code but the solution is fairly easy to implement.

Add a [`View.OnTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to your ImageView.

This listener will respond to every single touch event happening on the `View`. (touch down, move, touch up etc...)

You can retrieve the coordinate of the event with [`MotionEvent.getX(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getX(int)) (and y equivalent). (read [`MotionEvent` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getX(int)) to learn more about pointers).

When you have X and Y coordinates of the touch event, you can get the pixel color of the pointed pixel in the bitmap with [`Bitmap.getPixel(int, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel(int,%20int)) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306623/get-bitmap-attached-to-imageview) to get the `Bitmap` attached to your `ImageView`).

Voila, you have the selected color. Just print it into a rectangular view below your image view and use [Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) utility class to extract ARVB components of the selected color.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have implemented this however the coordinates it finds when i touch on the screen displays a colour that is slightly off from what it should be. I think this is because it is relative to the entire screen rather than the image view. Do you have any idea how i make it relative to the image view? http://pastebin.com/UbT48eJ1 @pdegand59

Comment: Or it is relative to the original image resolution instead of the scaled bitmap.