# Get Bitmap attached to ImageView with background

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8306623/3913366) SO question which suggested getting a Bitmap from an ImageView by just doing this :

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

The problem I am facing is, when I first set the `background` of an ImageView, followed by `src` and then using the suggested solution, I only get the bitmap as the `src` image. It didn't contained the `background` part of that `ImageView`. What am I missing here?

Comment: FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306623/get-bitmap-attached-to-imageview

Comment: @ChintanKhetiya Did you even read the question? The fourth word of this question provides the same question link as you provided which **isn't** working for me.

Comment: Your accepted answer is same answer which is already pointed by you via link and that's why i again point to check it to be more clear. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get bitmap using **DrawingCache**..
try following code:

```
image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

// this is the important code :)  
// Without it the view will have a dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will be null          
image.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
image.layout(0, 0, image.getMeasuredWidth(), image.getMeasuredHeight()); 

image.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getDrawingCache());
image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
```

Comment: This worked. Just that, with line `image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);`, it took time. When I removed this, lag was gone. However it worked in both cases. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can get layer of images by

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)((LayerDrawable)imageViewPlayPause.getDrawable()).getDrawable(0)).getBitmap(‌​);
```

get images by index 0 and 1, and check which image you get.