# How to generate a Bitmap from an ImageView for the Palette API?

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable, android-bitmap, palette

How can you generate a Bitmap from an image to use with the Palette API? I tried `imageView.getDrawable().getBitmap()`, but AS couldn't resolve `getBitmap()`, so I checked the source code of `Drawable`and this method doesn't seem to be there anymore.

I also set `imageView.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true`, and then used `imageView.drawingCache`, but that crashes the app with `IllegalArguementException: Bitmap is not valid`

Comment: there is no `Drawable#getBitmap()` method but there is `Drawable#draw()` which you can use for drawing the `Canvas`

Comment: but most likely (i guess 99%) `imageView.getDrawable()` returns  `BitmapDrawable` object, if so, you can call `getBitmap()` method on it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Bitmap attached to ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306623/get-bitmap-attached-to-imageview)